# How to add circles at the junction points of the Voronoi lines?

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, procedural, shader-nodes

As follows in the image, I would like to add circles of the points where the Voronoi lines join, as I did in my sketch.

I do not understand if it is possible, I would like if it is, to understand how to do it.

[image]

Comment: The circles are the seeds of the Voronoi pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram#Applications). I doubt that you can get them from the image. If you just need a bunch of circles connected by lines Geometry Nodes would be an easier approach.

Comment: The seeds are in the center of the cells, not on the interstices between them.  That having been said, some more info on the end goal might be helpful.  Working up a procedural mask of the interstices might be doable if all you want is dots, but if you want more control (borders for circles, different shapes, etc) then Blunder's probably right, Geometry Nodes would probably be better for you if feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Blender's Voronoi output is limited, and those 'points' are undefined, they are only the triple point of the boundary between cells. These are not points in memory, their specific coordinates are at no point calculated by the voronoi shader.

Blender's shader node programming is even more limited, it won't allow you to programatically affect nearby texels, each texel is computed independantly.

What you could do is bake your current lines to a texture, then via edge detecting, find all the triple points and place textures at each one.

This would of course be complicated, I don't know of a program to facilitate it. If I had to make this, I would use image libraries in python.

Alternatively, after baking, manually paste your circles on your texture.

(a more complex solution could be to build a custom voronoi implementation in GLSL and add computation of those points, and distance to those points)

Comment: I find this answer very useful. I was trying to mix 2 Voronoi, I am having fun learning more about these texture generators