# Add circles at boundary of cells in voronoi texture

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders

I'm looking to achieve a similar effect to this -- where there are circles at the cell boundaries of a voronoi texture, though ideally the circles would not be evenly spaced and I would be able to adjust the size and number of circles.

[image: voronoi with circles at boundaries]

I found [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/262283/how-to-add-circles-at-the-junction-points-of-the-voronoi-lines) to a previous and somewhat similar question in which the answer indicated that there is not a simple solution as blender does not track these points. However, in my case, I am not looking to place the circles only at the triple-points, but instead along the entire boundary. My apologies if this question has the same answer as the previous question linked above, but it was unclear whether they meant that blender didn't track the triple points or whether they didn't track the boundary in general.

Below is my current node setup and resulting texture.

[image: grains]

[image: grains nodes]

Answer (score 2):

This is as far as I was able to do do it within the shader alone:

[image]

[image]

[image]